# How to calculate standard error of a regression coefficient given R output

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear

Given the following regression equation

$mpg_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 weight_i+ \beta_2 ln(hp_i)+ \beta_3 diesel_i + \beta_4 ln(torque_i) + \beta_5 ln(torque_i) + \beta_6 year_i+\epsilon_i$

with the following R output:

[image: R out]

How to calculate the standard error of the dummy variable diesel (which is 1 when the car has a diesel engine, 0 otherwise)?

I know:

$\begin{matrix}\widehat{\text{se}}(\hat{b})=\sqrt{\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sum_i(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}\end{matrix}$

and

$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{N-K}\sum_i\hat{\epsilon}_i^2$

but neither $\sum_i(x_i-\bar{x})^2$ nor $\sum_i\hat{\epsilon}_i^2$ are given. Is there any way this is possible?

Comment: Note that $t = \beta/\operatorname{SE}$.

Answer (score 4):

Got it.

Solve the t-Statistics given in the output for the standard error.

$t-Value = 65.0 = \frac{6.5860610 - 0}{\hat{\sigma}_{diesel}}
\implies \hat{\sigma}_{diesel} = \frac{6.5860610}{65.0} = 0.1013240154 $